# Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals in plot

Tags: matrix, plot, 3d, indices

I am trying to plot existing data that is in matrices. When I attempt to plot I get the error:

"Subscript indices must either be real
positive integers or logicals."

Error in Plot_Displacement_Linear (line
35)
plot(xn(:),ucp(:),'rs',xn(:),ucp_actual(:),'g')

This is very odd as the ':' operator is not a specific index but just means, access all data as an array. It should have worked and has in the past. I investigated xn, ucp, and ucp_actual. They are 3D arrays as they correspond to positions in a volume but I am interested in plotting them only against xn, which is the current x position in the volume. Therefore I access them as xn(:), ucp(:), ucp_actual(:). I get this error as a result. This worked for 2D matrices I think, but is the first time I have fed 3D matrices through the code.

I investigated the arrays as given in the plot function, by defined new variables as:

```
xni = xn(:);
ucpi = ucp(:);
ucp_ai = ucp_actual(:);
```

they all come out as 1-D arrays that are all 404600x1 (double). So plot should have handled them all just fine. They are all the same length.

To see if it was just an glitch in the 3D-access, I then used the redefined variables above and tried:

```
plot(xni(:),ucpi(:),' rs',xni(:),ucp_ai(:),'g'),
plot(xni(:),ucpi(:),xni(:),ucp_ai(:)),
plot(xni,ucpi,xni,ucp_ai),
and finally: plot(xni,ucpi) and plot(xni',ucpi').
```

Nothing worked, all generated the identical error, even when there were no indices being accessed to speak of and only two vectors of the same length. Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

thanks in advance,

Dan M

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** okay, I think I solved the issue, after trying the following I knew something deeper was wrong:

```
>> ans = [1;2;3];
>> ans2 = [1;2;3];
>> plot(ans,ans2)
Error: 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions.'
```

There are no indices again, and I just defined these arrays. After investigating my datafield I discovered I had defined a variable called "plot" so it was confused. I'm surprised matlab even let me do this. After using 'clear plot' the code worked perfectly. sorry for the trouble.